# How to update nested array without ID in object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I know this has been asked a number of times before but I can't seem to find the answer, How to update in nested array but objet in nested array without id???

```js
const hasil = await Setting.update(
            { _id: Id, 'value.name': req.body.name },
            { "$set": { 'value.value': req.body.value } }
        )
```

```js
{
    "_id" : 1234567,
    "key" : "version",
    "name" : "Collection Version",
    "value" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "categories",
            "value" : 7
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "tag",
            "value" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "article",
            "value" : 3
        }, 
        
    ],
}
```

Comment: The `"value"` is of type `array`. Your mongo query won't work because you're treating it as if it's an object.

Comment: ok, solved added $, value.$.value thanks